# Python code for Edge Data Bevel and Crease Weight?

Tags: python, interface

Anybody has an idea what the python code is to draw the edge data bevel and crease weight sliders?

[image]

It seems not to be part of "space_view3d.py"

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, but this submenu is defined in C, not python -- (you can see this by rightclicking any of the sliders and trying to edit-source). I think you'll have to do a little bit of coding :)

Comment: Thats the impression I got as well. Is it possible to write a script that shows a slider and the value is uses as for edge crease or bevel weight?  I found the commands that adjust the edge data and the thing that might store the data?
bpy.types.MeshEdge
bpy.ops.transform.edge_bevelweight(value=0.366871)
bpy.ops.transform.edge_crease(value=-0.315626)

Answer (score 7):

**EDITED**:

OK, apparently the previous answer was pretty worthless. Although there is a `meshedge.crease` property and a `meshvertex.bevel_weight` property, they do not influence modifiers at all, and their values do not change when changing the corresponding values in the properties panel.

However, there is a way to access these values through custom layers via BMESH. The addon below adds a panel that allows you to influence selected verts / edges or all verts / edges' crease and bevel weight properties.

[image]

It does have one weird bug though, which seems to be a bug in Blender, as seen in the GIF above. Even though this does indeed update the respective mesh properites, Blender does not update the display until you also change any value of a modifier on the active mesh.

**EDITED 2:**

Thanks to a comment from batFINGER, found a solution to the weird behavior mentioned and seen above: adding a `bmesh.update_edit_mesh( meshData )` after updating the crease / bevel values. Updated code below accordingly.

To use this, download the code and save it as a python (.py) file on your computer, then install it as an addon (File --> User Preferences --> Add-ons --> Install From File).

The panel appears in Edit Mode only in the Tools tab, under "Crease and Bevel".

```
bl_info = {
    "name"       : "Crease and Bevel weight panel",
    "version"    : (0, 0, 1),
    "blender"    : (2, 77, 0),
    "category"   : "Tools",
    "location"   : "3D View > Toolbox",
    "description": "Shortcut UI panel for Mesh edge crease and vertex bevel weight properties"
}

import bpy, bmesh

class creaseAndBevelPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname      = "creaseAndBevelPanel"
    bl_label       = "Crease and Bevel"
    bl_space_type  = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category    = 'Tools'
    bl_context     = "mesh_edit"

    @classmethod
    def poll( self, context ):
        ''' Only show panel if there is an active mesh object '''
        return context.object and context.object.type == 'MESH'

    def draw( self, context ):
            layout = self.layout
            props  = context.scene.creaseAndBevelPG # Create reference to property group

            box = layout.box()                    # Draw a box
            col = box.column( align = True )      # Create a column
            col.prop( props, "whoToInfluence"  )  # Add properites to panel
            col.prop( props, "bevelWeight"     )
            col.prop( props, "edgeCrease"      )

class creaseAndBevelPG(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    ## Update functions
    def update_bevelWeight( self, context ):
        ''' Update function for bevelWeight property '''

        o  = bpy.context.object
        d  = o.data
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh( d )

        bevelWeightLayer = bm.verts.layers.bevel_weight['BevelWeight']

        if self.whoToInfluence == 'Selected Elements':
            selectedVerts = [ v for v in bm.verts if v.select ]
            for v in selectedVerts: v[ bevelWeightLayer ] = self.bevelWeight
        else:
            for v in bm.verts: v[ bevelWeightLayer ] = self.bevelWeight

        bmesh.update_edit_mesh( d )

    def update_edgeCrease( self, context ):
        ''' Update function for edgeCrease property '''

        o  = bpy.context.object
        d  = o.data
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh( d )

        creaseLayer = bm.edges.layers.crease['SubSurfCrease']

        if self.whoToInfluence == 'Selected Elements':
            selectedEdges = [ e for e in bm.edges if e.select ]
            for e in selectedEdges: e[ creaseLayer ] = self.edgeCrease
        else:
            for e in bm.edges: e[ creaseLayer ] = self.edgeCrease

        bmesh.update_edit_mesh( d )

    ## Properties
    items = [
        ('All', 'All', ''),
        ('Selected Elements', 'Selected Elements', '')
    ]

    whoToInfluence = bpy.props.EnumProperty( # Material distribution method
        description = "Influence all / selection",
        name        = "whoToInfluence",
        items       = items,
        default     = 'Selected Elements'
    )

    bevelWeight = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        description = "Bevel Weight",
        name        = "bevelWeight",
        min         = 0.0,
        max         = 1.0,
        step        = 0.01,
        default     = 0,
        update      = update_bevelWeight
    )

    edgeCrease = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        description = "Edge Crease",
        name        = "edgeCrease",
        min         = 0.0,
        max         = 1.0,
        step        = 0.01,
        default     = 0,
        update      = update_edgeCrease
    )

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.creaseAndBevelPG = bpy.props.PointerProperty( type = creaseAndBevelPG )

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
```

Comment: Thank you - have to google how I could turn this into a UI.

Comment: I know this thread is very old. But what is the solution here?

Comment: @Tiles, in terms of how to implement this via a UI panel?

Comment: Yes :) :) :) :)

Comment: @Tiles, see updated answer.

Comment: Ah, the BMesh approach. Thanks for this example TLousky. Now i just need to understand it ^^ For the update part, maybe area.tag_redraw will lead to a solution here?

Comment: Tried all kinds of redraws and updates (context.scene.update(), object.modifiers.update() and the tag_redraw function), nothing really works. It's really weird since usually, when you move the 3D view the scene is redrawn and everything is updated, but in this case I found that only changing a modifier's property did the trick.

Comment: Too bad. Nevertheless thanks for your investigation and help :)

Comment: It does have one weird bug though, which seems to be a bug in Blender, <- @TLousky, just curious, shouldn't we report it as a bug then?

Comment: @Tiles, yeah, if it is truly a bug. I was hoping maybe some other guys here would comment on the matter to confirm or deny my suspicion before bothering the devs with another bug report.

Comment: Well. I can confirm the behaviour. And i don't know a solution neither. In worst case the devs would simply deny the report. Would you be so kind to report it? I fear my skills are too weak to explain the bug really in detail and indepth.

Comment: How about a `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(d)` at end of update method? quick test looks good for edge crease....

Comment: Awesome @batFINGER, works like a charm, will update answer.

Comment: You folks are awesome :)

Comment: Hm, i fear we have still an update problem. When i change the values in the original Transform panel, then the values in the addon does not update.

Comment: That's going to be a whole lot more tricky, since the panel is a way for you apply crease and bevel weight values on either all or the selected verts / edges. These values could be different for different mesh elements, which is why average values are shown in the props panel when more than one element is selected. Not impossible to do, but requires quite a lot more logics that's a bit beyond the scope of this particular problem (of accessing these values via a script or the UI).