# Python code for Transform panel content in edit mode?

Tags: python, scripting, panel

I'm at redoing the Transform panel. I want to put the Item content into it too to save some space. And want to put it at another location.

Most things are working. What i cannot access is the panel content in Edit mode for Mesh, Curve and Surface. These menu items are C code.

Items like Bevel Weigth and Crease are part of the Python API though. And so i hope that there is a way this way around. How do i rebuild those props and access items like Bevel Weight here to have an equal result like in the offical Transform panel?

[image]

Comment: Hm, thanks poor, but what is the relation?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56385/python-edit-panel-to-edit-custom-bmesh-face-layers/56452#56452  for meshes it sets up an 'EDIT' mode global edit bmesh.  Code your Panel using that bmesh.  Similarly for other data types (without the bmesh).

Comment: @Tiles Oops. Sorry, misread the question.

Comment: No problem :) I am a bit lost with the advice in batFINGER's related thread though. Seems that this fish is too big for me at the moment ^^

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44787/python-code-for-edge-data-bevel-and-crease-weight