# Displaying and changing selected edges Mean Crease in python

Tags: python, scripting

I'm building a custom menu using Serpens and python and I'm trying to recreate the same behavior than the menu we can find in the Item tab:

[image]

In order to do that I have this little code I'm using in Serpens

```
import bmesh

o  = bpy.context.object
d  = o.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh( d )

creaseLayer = bm.edges.layers.crease.verify()

selectedEdges = [ e for e in bm.edges if e.select ]
for e in selectedEdges: e[ creaseLayer ] = crease_weight

bmesh.update_edit_mesh( d )
```

This was made by looking at this previous post regarding a similar query from the past:
[Python code for Edge Data Bevel and Crease Weight?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44787/python-code-for-edge-data-bevel-and-crease-weight)

However since Blender 4.0 it seems like the way to edit Creases changed and this code doesn't work anymore.
What would be the best way to re-create this behavior now.

I've looked into
**bpy.ops.transform.edge_crease(value=newCreaseValue)** and **edge_creases_ensure** but I'm not sure how to properly use them in my case.

Apologies for my lack and knowledge and thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

Solution found: We have to use this line to get the Crease layer, as Crease as been moved to a named float attribute:

```
creaseLayer = bm.edges.layers.float.get('crease_edge', None) if bpy.app.version >= (4,0,0) else bm.edges.layers.crease.active
```

Comment: I think replacing the verify() line by: creaseLayer = bm.edges.layers.float.verify() should do it.

Comment: Indeed! It fixes the issue! I'm not sure what does this mean. I'll do some research to understand it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure either... is float supposed to be crease systematically in this version? I don't know...

Comment: Actually it only worked the first time I tried it but somehow on other objects and after exporting the addon, it only turns the edges blue. It doesn't really change the Crease attribute. The float.verify creates a custom data layer. How can I propagate it back to the Crease attribute?
Here are the changed I found regarding 4.0 
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Python_API

Vertex and edge crease have been moved to generic attributes as well, with the names crease_vert and crease_edge.

But I'm not sure what to do about this information..

Comment: just a guess as I've not verified that: before creating/verifying the layer, check if it exists already.

Comment: Thanks lemon, here is the solution if anybody faces the same issue, with backward compatibility.

creaseLayer = bm.edges.layers.float.get('crease_edge', None) if bpy.app.version >= (4,0,0) else bm.edges.layers.crease.active